# How to check for start and stop with spring framework?

Tags: java, spring

Hi I need to send an email when my application starts and and email when my application stops.

Using spring...

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FileSystemXmlApplicationContext fac = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("config/applicationContext.xml");
    }
}
```

The rest is wired up through the application context...

I suppose I can just inject a simple bean that implements smart life cycle and send an email from within the `start()` and `stop()` methods?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply use a bean in default singleton scope, and declare its init and destroy method. The bean need no adherence to Spring and could be something like :

```
public class StartAndStop {

    public void onStart() {
        // send the mail signaling start of application
        ...
    }

    public void onStop() {
        // send the mail signaling stop of application
        ...
    }
}
```

In xml config :

```
<bean class="org.example.StartAndStop" init-method="onStart" destroy-method="onStop"/>
```

And with Java configuration

```
@Configuration
public class Configurer {

    @Bean(initMethod="onStart", destroyMethod="onStop")
    StartAndStop startAndStop() {
        return new StartAndStop();
    }
    ... other beans configuration ...
}
```

Of course, you can also use spring to set properties on the bean ...

Comment: Both equally good answers but in my situation I picked this approach and marked it as the accepted answer. :)

Comment: Also worth mentioning for this to work right you also need to registerShutdownHook().

Comment: @user432024 : is the JVM closes without the container shutting down properly its servlet contextes, things are really going bad and you are not sure to be able to do anything :-(

Comment: I know, there's no guarantee shutdown will complete or not get interrupted, but without registerShutDownhook() stop method of bean never got called until I registered the shut down hook.

Answer (score 2):

Spring automatically raises events in these sitatuations.

You can listen for events by creating an `ApplicationListener` bean:

```
@Component
public class ContextRefreshListener implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {

  @Override
  public void onApplicationEvent(final ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
    // is called whenever the application context is initialized or refreshed
  }
}
```

Spring raises the following application context events:

- [ContextClosedEvent](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/event/ContextClosedEvent.html) (ApplicationContext gets closed)
- [ContextRefreshedEvent](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/event/ContextRefreshedEvent.html) (ApplicationContext gets initialized or refreshed)
- [ContextStartedEvent](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/event/ContextStartedEvent.html) (ApplicationContext gets stopped)
- [ContextStoppedEvent](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/event/ContextStoppedEvent.html) (ApplicationContext gets stopped)

See [Standard and Custom Events documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#context-functionality-events)

Comment: Ok I try and let you know. Thanks

Comment: Do I need to explicitely call? new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
  cac.start();

Comment: It seems I need to explicitly call start() and stop(). Only the refresh event is published automatically.